# Hadoop bin directory does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

Program:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE icebergdb2")
spark.sql("USE icebergdb2")
schema = StructType([
  StructField("vendor_id", LongType(), True),
  StructField("trip_id", LongType(), True),
  StructField("trip_distance", FloatType(), True),
  StructField("fare_amount", DoubleType(), True),
  StructField("store_and_fwd_flag", StringType(), True)
])
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE icebergdb2.iceberg_table (vendor_id LONG, trip_id LONG, trip_distance FLOAT, fare_amount DOUBLE, store_and_fwd_flag STRING) USING iceberg")
```

Getting this error while executing the above program:

```
WARN Shell: Did not find winutils.exe: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Hadoop bin directory does not exist: C:\Users\abc\Desktop\ice\hadoop-3.3.1\etc\hadoop\bin -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\ice\ice.py", line 24, in <module>
    spark.sql("CREATE TABLE icebergdb2.iceberg_table \
  File "C:\Users\abc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 1034, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self)
  File "C:\Users\abc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Users\abc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)  
PS C:\Users\abc\Desktop\ice> SUCCESS: The process with PID 1204 (child process of PID 8780) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 8780 (child process of PID 14136) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 14136 (child process of PID 14132) has been terminated.
```

To create an Apache iceberg table using Apache Spark.

Comment: Can you verify that you set HADOOP_HOME environment variable accordingly and added %HADOOP_HOME%\bin to path ?

Comment: Download the Spark version that includes Hadoop. Pyspark doesn't come with it

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're trying to run Spark on windows. For this, you need a tool called "winutils". In your error message, you can see `Did not find winutils.exe: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Hadoop bin directory does not exist`.

Let's see what the steps are you must take to have a properly running Spark instance on your PC:

1. [Download](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) Spark pre-built with Hadoop. For example, `spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz`.
2. Extract this file and copy the extracted folder to a place you want it to end up in. For example, `C:\Spark`
3. Make an environment variable called `SPARK_HOME` and point that to the folder you just extracted and moved (`C:\Spark` from point 2).
4. Add `%SPARK_HOME%/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable. This enables you to run spark commands like `spark-submit` and `spark-shell`.

Now you've installed Spark! To make it run properly on Windows, we now need to make this winutils tool work:

1. Download `winutils.exe` and `hadoop.dll` from [this website](https://github.com/kontext-tech/winutils). Since these were pre-compiled on a 64 bit JVM, you must make sure that you have a 64 bit JDK installation. You can of course use other ones if you prefer, just giving an example here.
2. Move them over to some folder you like, within a folder called `bin`. For example, `C:\hadoop\bin`.
3. Make the `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable, and point it to the parent folder of that bin folder you put the 2 files in. In the previous example, it would be `C:\hadoop`.
4. Add `%HADOOP_HOME%/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.
5. Start up a new terminal session (git bash, powershell, cmd, ...)

When you've done all these things, your problem should be gone!